# Simple filesize output terminal

Tags: command-line, files

Is there a simple command in the terminal (or a command with a usage that I know not) that would output filesize in bytes of a file given a filename parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `stat` command

```
stat -c '%s' filename
```

See `man stat` for details and other options

Or, with `du`

```
du -b filename
```

Comment: I like the stat better: it just gives file size as requested.  I will accept it as soon as I am allowed to